# Ignoring mypy attr-defined with triple quotes

Tags: python, mypy

The following code:

```py
# type: ignore[attr-defined]
timeit.template = """  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
def inner(_it, _timer{init}):
    {setup}
    _t0 = _timer()
    for _i in _it:
        retval = {stmt}
    _t1 = _timer()
    return _t1 - _t0, retval
"""  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
# type: ignore[attr-defined]
```

Yields error:

```
src/snncompare/Experiment_runner.py:45: error: Module has no attribute "template"  [attr-defined]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 97 source files)
```

How can I ensure mypy ignores only this one instance of the creation of the attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use implicit line continuation with parentheses, so you can put a comment on the first line of the assignment:

```
timeit.template = (  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
"""
def inner(_it, _timer{init}):
    {setup}
    _t0 = _timer()
    for _i in _it:
        retval = {stmt}
    _t1 = _timer()
    return _t1 - _t0, retval
""")
```

If you want something less prone to getting messed up by autoformatters, you can introduce an intermediate variable:

```
template = """
def inner(_it, _timer{init}):
    {setup}
    _t0 = _timer()
    for _i in _it:
        retval = {stmt}
    _t1 = _timer()
    return _t1 - _t0, retval
"""

timeit.template = template  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
```

That said, your use case is a bad idea. It will mess with all uses of `timeit` anywhere in the process, including library code you had no idea needed `timeit`. If you want to know what an expression evaluates to, just evaluate it once, outside of the `timeit` call.

Comment: Thank you for the additional warning. When I apply your solution, `black-conda` reformats it to my original code, with the `""" # type: ignore[attr-defined]` at the end.

Comment: @a.t.: Moving comments around is a known limitation of `black`. I've added a second approach that I *think* `black` won't mess with, but you'll probably run into more issues like this.

Comment: Thank you, creative solution, your second option resolved the issue, and pre-commit was happy.